# Result given for and operator predicate (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, predicate

Someone is occupied and it is defined by if someone works two jobs.

Given the following descriptions

```
employe(tom,shopify).
employe(eva,shopify).
employe(eva,ibm).
employe(sam,cisco).
employe(sam,bridehead).
```

I want to modify the following predicate to return the people who work two jobs.

```
occupe(X):- employe(X,C1), employe(X,C2).
```

I don't understand why tom is given as a possible answer when he only works one job (i.e I don't get how the and operator `,` doesn't make sure that the employee works two separate jobs).

Additionally, I've tried adding `!` at the beginning but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `C1`  and `C2` are the same.

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that this works is because `C1` and `C2` are not per se different. It thus unifies both `C1` and `C2` with `shopify`.

In order to determine people that work at two different jobs, you should specify that `C1` and `C2` should be different:

```
occupe(X):- employe(X,C1), employe(X,C2), C1 \= C2.
```